# ExtJs gridPanel Dynamic Cell Background colour from Record.Data

Tags: css, extjs, gridpanel

I'm working with ExtJs 4.2 in PHP, creating a grid with a Store that reads information from a SQL DB to populate the rows. One of the columns relates to the status of the row (open, closed etc.), and another relates to a hexadecimal colour value that in previous code was applied to the background colour of the table cell.

I've read about using the renderer config option on the related column to apply a CSS class (both in a separate CSS file and as raw text) that contains the desired colour, but I'm working off specific colours that are retrieved as part of a row's data.

I thought code for a column along the lines of below would work, but it doesn't.

How would I get this functionality? Many of the examples are using "if" logic to determine the colour to render, but I only need to render the one colour that is supplied in the data from the store. Having a list of classes isn't desirable, as these colours could change in the database, or new statuses could be added; it would be preferable to call the colour value from the data.

```
{text: "Status",
 sortable: true,
 width:100,
 dataIndex: 'Status',
 renderer: function(value, meta, record){
                    meta.attr = 'style="color:#'record.data.StatusColour'"';
                    return value;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    //Define the model
    Ext.define('CaseModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            reader: 'json'
        },
        fields: [
            'Id',
            'Project',
            'Status',
            'StatusColour',
        ]
    });

    // create the Data Store
    var caseStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'CaseModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            // load using HTTP
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '<?= $site_url ?>Case/JSON/All',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                model: 'CaseModel',
                root: 'data'
            }
        },
        remoteSort: true,
        pageSize: 20
    });

    //Render grid
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        width: 800,
        store: caseStore,
        title: 'Cases',
        columns: [
            {text: "ID", sortable: true, width: 25, dataIndex: 'Id'},
            {text: "Project", sortable: true, width: 100, dataIndex: 'Project'},
            {text: "Status", sortable: true, width:100, dataIndex: 'Status'
            // renderer goes here
            /*
            , renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                meta.style = 'background-color: ' + record.get('StatusColour');
                return value;
            }
            */
            },
            {text: 'Details', xtype: 'templatecolumn', width: 50, tpl: '<a class=\"link_btn\" href=\"<?php echo site_url()?>Case/View/{Id}\">Open</a>'}
        ],
        renderTo: Ext.get('CaseGrid'),
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            itemId: 'PagingToolbar',
            displayInfo: true,
            store: caseStore
        }],
        features: [
            {ftype: 'grouping'}
        ]
    });
});

//Sample JSON data
{
    "total":"17",
    "data":
    [
        {"Id":"64","Project":"test case 1","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"49","Project":"fgdfgdfgdfg","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"65","Project":"test case 2","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"50","Project":"abc","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"51","Project":"aaaa","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"67","Project":"test case 4","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"52","Project":"fffffff","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"37","Project":"ghfdgh","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"53","Project":"ddddddddd","Status":"New","StatusColour":"ffffff"},
        {"Id":"29","Project":"Suppress 0 value line items to SOP","Status":"Open","StatusColour":"6dce6d"},
        {"Id":"66","Project":"test case 3","Status":"Open","StatusColour":"6dce6d"},
        {"Id":"16","Project":"Egress locks","Status":"Postponed","StatusColour":"cd7ddb"},
        {"Id":"63","Project":"Public Comment2","Status":"Duplicated","StatusColour":"bf6161"},
        {"Id":"30","Project":"Nominal codes for Stock items","Status":"Duplicated","StatusColour":"bf6161"},
        {"Id":"17","Project":"Details missing","Status":"Closed","StatusColour":"777777"},
        {"Id":"18","Project":"Non-standard finish not priced","Status":"Closed","StatusColour":"777777"},
        {"Id":"19","Project":"POA and VAT Rate","Status":"Closed","StatusColour":"777777"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the docs, the [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer)'s parameter "meta" supports the following properties: tdCls, tdAttr, and style.

So in your case, style would be suitable:

```
{
    text: "Status",
    sortable: true,
    width: 100,
    dataIndex: 'Status',
    renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
        meta.style = 'background-color: #' + record.get('StatusColour');
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Inspecting the code doesn't show any particular errors in FireBug, other than a  "b.getRowStyleTableEl(...) is null" error when the mouse hovers over a cell with the applied renderer.

It looks as though the StatusColour isn't being found, and I know it exists from the JSON response; What is the best way to ensure the value is being converted to a string to display correctly, or at least check that the value is getting from the response to the grid?

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(record);` or a `debugger;` to the renderer and inspect the content of `record.data`. I don't think the above code would throw an JavaScript error if the StatusColour is null, but you could also try adding a condition before applying the `meta.style` (that's probably a good idea anyway to make sure only valid style code is generated in all cases).

Comment: I put in console.log(record), which pulls the entire set of requests; the JSON returned from the server has a "total" and "data" setup; console.log(record.data) is more meaningful as it shows the record's information, yet changing record.get('StatusColour') to record.data.get('StatusColour') stops the column and subsequent columns from rendering. How would I get the record.data.StatusColour value if it doesn't drill down further into the JSON?

Comment: `record.get('StatusColour')` is equivalent to `record.data['StatusColour']` resp. `record.data.StatusColour`. Try inspecting that. If it's null or an empty string or even undefined, then probably something is wrong with your store, model (mapping) or server data. It might also be helpful to add your store & model definition and sample JSON data here for further analysis.

Comment: I've added store and model code and sample JSON data, as well as the grid as it stands. The JSON data is pulled from the Firebug Console GET request response for the page, which shows it is retrieving the colour notation per row, it just isn't being seen by the grid - "background-color: " is shown in the style section when I inspect the cell in Firebug.

Comment: Thanks for providing detailed information. I've ran your test case and it seems that you're missing the `#` in front of the status color in your renderer (see the renderer function of my original answer). The browser needs that to know that you're using a hexadecimal color code, otherwise it will just ignore the value.

Comment: It is now actually working - I thought I'd tried with the `#` previously and it wasn't working, but I'd best not knock it. Thanks for the help.